# Not skewed text in skewed class button

Tags: html, css

I've created a button for my website with a CSS class and I wanted it to have a parallelogram shape so I've used the skew function to create the shape. The code was right and the button has the shape that I wanted but the text inside the button resulted skewed as well following its wrap. There's a way to make the text not looking like the Leaning Tower inside my button?
Here's the html code:

```
<input type="submit" alt="submit" value="Login" class="button">
```

And that's the CSS for the button class:

```
.button {
    float: top;
    width: 275px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Impact;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(20deg);
    -o-transform: skewX(20deg);
    transform: skewX(20deg);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partly seconding Sidharth, I think you won't get around the wrapper element to apply the CSS-transform on and then reset it for its child elements (the submit-input):

```
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <input type="submit" alt="submit" value="Login">
</div>
```

Sidharth's answer implies that you completely hide the original `<input>` and relies on JavaScript to trigger a click on it when the styled wrapper is clicked, but here's and easy way around that: Style the `button-wrapper` on `:hover` and remove all styles from the nested `<input>`-element and make it 100% wide ([jsBin example](http://jsbin.com/obusoy/6/edit)):

```
.button-wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-color: #ddd #ccc #bbb;
  overflow: hidden;

  -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
  -moz-transform: skewX(20deg);
  -o-transform: skewX(20deg);
  transform: skewX(20deg);
}

.button-wrapper:hover {
  background: #efe;
  border-color: #090;
}

.button-wrapper input {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;

  -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -o-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
}

.button-wrapper input:hover {
  color: #060;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know years have past, but I just ran into this same problem and found that simply doing the reverse skew on the text solved my problem, as follows in my code:

```
.yellowShape {
     background-color: rgba(244,255,88,0.92);
     padding: 3px;
     -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
     transform: skew(20deg); 
}

.yellowShape p {
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
    transform: skew(-20deg); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper for the "button" and put the text inside that. However, you would need to use javascript to trigger a "click" on the button if the text is clicked as it would not otherwise "propagate" to the button.